# .net Dependent assembly of dependent assembly not loaded from GAC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac

**The `GAC` contains `system.net.http 2.0.0.0`, however the build process complains that it cannot be found:**

```
The primary reference "ABC.dll" could not be resolved 
because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly 
"System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. 
".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".
```

Both `ABC.dll` and my current project are targeting `.NET Framework 4`

Output from `gacutil -l` displays both versions:

[image]

```
System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

**Additionally tried:**
Changing the machine config to no avail

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**Can't do:**
Change the .csproj, .net version or bundle the right .dll with the app. Because the abc.dll and the system.net.http dependencies are deployed to client machines as part of GAC, therefore only changes allowed are to my dev machine.

Comment: Reference assemblies never come from the GAC, it doesn't do what it does until you run your program.  So what you've been looking at so far isn't going to solve this problem.  Where you are going to get the reference assembly from is murky, v2.0.0.0 is quite old and System.Net.Http has massive DLL Hell problems. You might try using an ancient release of the nuget package.  Having such a large major version difference is not healthy of course, rebuilding abc.dll would be wise.

Comment: Yep, ended up getting it from nuget under Microsoft.net.http package

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Misconception: reference assemblies come from the GAC during compilation.
Actually they don't.

You can change the verbosity of the build log to `diagnostic` and see where and which assemblies are being searched. (`Vs Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build & Run -> Verbosity`)

**Fix**

Under `solution explorer` -> `right click on project` -> `properties` -> `reference paths` Add the directory containing whatever assemblies you are missing.

Additionally, you can do it on the machine level, by editing
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\AssemblyFolders.config`